# remove na in a specific column of a dataframe

Tags: r, tidyr, na

I have the following code, yet when i run the last line (the linear regression), it indicates a message of error : "Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf dans 'y'". Would you know how to fix this ?

```
annee_N <- cbind(df_amb$A,
                 df_amb$B,
                 df_amb$C/df_amb$A,
                 rep("2021", nrow(df_amb)))
annee_N1 <- cbind(df_amb$A,
                  df_amb$B,
                  df_amb$C/df_amb$A,
                  rep("2020", nrow(df_amb)))
annee_N2 <- cbind(df_amb$A,
                  df_amb$B,
                  df_amb$C/df_amb$A,
                  rep("2019", nrow(df_amb)))

reg_spé_amb <- data.frame(rbind(annee_N, annee_N1, annee_N2))
colnames(reg_spé_amb) <- c("A", "B", "C", 
"année")
lm_amb <- lm(reg_spé_amb[,3] ~ reg_spé_amb[,2] + reg_spé_amb[,1] + reg_spé_amb[,4])
```

My dataframe reg_spé_amb has the following structure :

```
A                      B                            C

anes                  10                          500                  2019
chir                  11                          600                  2019
anes                  9                           450                  2020
```

I have tried to remove NAs appearing in the 3rd column of my dataframe reg_spé_amb in two ways at the end of my code:

```
library(tidyr)
reg_spé_amb %>%
   drop_na(reg_spé_amb[,3])

reg_spé_amb[!is.na(reg_spé_amb[,3])]
```

both times i got messages of error : "colonnes non définies sélectionnées" and "can't subset columns that don't exist". Yet the 3rd column does exist... could anyone help ?

Comment: try reg_spé_amb<-reg_spé_amb[complete.cases(reg_spé_amb),] and then run it again

Comment: try:
    drop_na(col_name)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: i am trying currently to delete posts but couldn't make it, this is why i have edited to remove the post, didn't know that was "vandalizing"... sorry

Comment: If you read the post I linked before, [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221), you'll see which questions can be deleted by yourself. TL;DR: anything with 0 answers or 1 answer that doesn't have any upvotes. In other words, you *can* delete this post. Also, *everything* you post on Stack Overflow is public and publicly licensed for re-use (including the revisions!), so you'll want to think twice before posting proprietary code, ad-verbatim homework your prof will find and anything else you don't want to be publicly searchable.